# Template is working for Excel2003 but not for Excel2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2003

I created an Excel worksheet (Book.xlt) under

- C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART

with my own setting.

That settings are occurring only for Excel2003(.xls) but not for Excel2007(.xlxs).

How can i make that settings also for Excel 2007

On my PC MS Office 2003 installed and I am opening and modifying MS Office2007 files via File Format converter software.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving your book1.xlt file as a book.xltx (2007 template format) in the same XLSTART folder.

Comment: Even after saving template with .xltx it showing some warnings and then changes are not reflecting

Answer (score 0):

Here are the [instructions for customizing starting templates for Excel 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/customize-how-excel-starts-HP010197489.aspx?CTT=1#BM3). Please note that you must create the template in Excel 2007 to ensure full compatibility.